# The method loadAnimation in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: android, animation, nullpointerexception

When I try to create an animation using the following code I get the following error:

> The method loadAnimation(context,int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments(MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment,int)

```
Animation textAnimation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.text_animation);
```

I also get a null pointer exception. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to call this function from inside the PlaceholderFragment that is declared inside MainActivity. loadAnimation expects a context in the first parameter. You can fix this problem by chNging the first argument from "this" to either getActivity() or to MainActivity.this

Answer (score 4):

i think `this` is something which is not equal to `Context`, try replacing below code.

```
Animation textAnimation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.text_animation);
```

**EDIT:** if you are using this code inside Fragment  then call `getActivity().getContext()` instead `this`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
```